# How to rearrange my data? split and transpose

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I have raw data with several pieces of information in one cell separated by a special symbol. I would like to be able to rearrange the data into rows but keeping the same ID, name, first name and age.

Please see the image below:

[image: Example]

I tried with filters, queries, splits and transpose but I haven't been able to make it work.

The link to my google sheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ECBAJ9jpqmohKAHl-Kpqp1cK5dGW3JiDC38WsWkuzSQ/edit#gid=352138315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(
 IF(A3:A9<>"", "♥"&A3:A9&"♦"&B3:B9&"♦"&C3:C9&"♦"&D3:D9, ), 
 LEN(REGEXREPLACE(""&E3:E9, "[^]+", )))), "♥")), "♦"),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, E3:E9), "")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, F3:F9), "")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, G3:G9), "")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("", 1, H3:H9), ""))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi Player! Thank you so much for your help!!!

I just have one more question, thanks to your answer I managed to created a spreadsheet but now I would like to search the code on a list of codes and return the name of the course.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YmQyyWh5XS6CC6mdlztHegNtZ1I6GHP_fsgieNSnRt4/edit?usp=sharing

In the tab Calculations there is a column called course name, I tried combining Index and Match but I cannot make it work. I would really appreciate if you could help one last time :)

Comment: use: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"Course Name"; IFNA(VLOOKUP(F3:F, 'Code List'!A:C, 2, 0))})`